# Replace value in one column with value from another column in the same row with certain condition BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to replace values in one column with values from another column if condition is met.
Data looks like this:

```
FieldName Previous 
AA         1
null       1
null       0
BB         1
BB         1
```

I want to replace value 1 in column Previous with the value in FieldName in the same row, but only when FieldName is not null.

Output:

```
FieldName Previous 
AA         AA
null       1
null       0
BB         BB
BB         BB
```

I've read the documentation about CAST and REPLACE, but was unable to apply it to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT FieldName, 
  IF(FieldName IS NULL, Previous, FieldName) AS Previous
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'AA' FieldName, '1' Previous UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, '1' UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, '0' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BB', '1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BB', '1' 
)
SELECT FieldName, 
  IF(FieldName IS NULL, Previous, FieldName) AS Previous
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row FieldName   Previous     
1   AA          AA   
2   null        1    
3   null        0    
4   BB          BB   
5   BB          BB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use update command to achieve this in the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE `testdataset.t1` (
  `FieldName` STRING,
  `Previous` STRING,
);

insert into `testdataset.t1`
values ('AA','1'), (null,'1'),(null,'0'),('BB','1'),('BB','1');

UPDATE `testdataset.t1`
SET Previous = FieldName
where FieldName is not null;
```